# checkKey Enter button issue in program

Tags: javascript

For some reason, when I add an Enter button value for the `checkKey` function in JavaScript, the whole program ceases to work. I tried looking up the correct numerical value for the Enter button in JavaScript, which is 13 according to some website, but the program is still not working. Help!

**HTML**

```
  <button type="leftButton" onClick="leftClick()">Left</button>
  <p>Clicks: <a id="leftClicks">0</a></p>

  <button type="rightButton" onClick="rightClick()">Right</button>
  <p>Clicks: <a id="rightClicks">0</a></p>

  <input type="button" onClick="save()" value="save" />
  <p>Save: <a id="saveClicks"></a></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Left counter
var leftClicks = 0;
  function leftClick() {
    leftClicks += 1;
    document.getElementById('leftClicks').innerHTML = leftClicks;
  }

// Right counter
var rightClicks = 0;
  function rightClick() {
    rightClicks += 1;
    document.getElementById('rightClicks').innerHTML = rightClicks;
  }

// Save
function save() {
  document.getElementById('saveClicks').innerHTML = leftClicks + " " + rightClicks;
}

// L/R key actions
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
  function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
      leftClicks += 1;
      document.getElementById('leftClicks').innerHTML = leftClicks;
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
      rightClicks += 1;
      document.getElementById('rightClicks').innerHTML = rightClicks;
    } else if (e.keyCode == '90') {
      leftClicks -= 1;
      document.getElementById('leftClicks').innerHTML = leftClicks;
    } else if (e.keyCode == '88') {
      rightClicks -= 1;
      document.getElementById('rightClicks').innerHTML = rightClicks;
    } else if (e.keyCode == '82') {
      leftClicks = 0;
      rightClicks = 0;
      document.getElementById('leftClicks').innerHTML = leftClicks;
      document.getElementById('rightClicks').innerHTML = rightClicks;
    } else if (e.keyCode == '13') {
      function save();
    }
  }
```

So, the problem is that when I add the following line of code to the program, it stops working altogether. Why is that?

```
else if (e.keyCode == '13') {
  function save();
}
```

Comment: Because the keyword `function` isn't valid there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the save function properly when enter is pressed, you would do:

```
else if(e.keyCode == '13') {
    save();
}
```

The word `function` should not be there when invoking an already declared function.
If you wanted to have an `anonymous` function that calls `save`, you could do:

```
else if(e.keyCode == '13') {
    function(){
        save();
    }
}
```